# how to find a parent class and its children

Tags: jquery

I have a structure of elements similar to the one down below.

```
<div class="Order_Wrapper">
    <div class="Order_left">
        <div class="Order_Subtotal">
            <span class="Order_Coupon"> (-)$
                <span class="Coupon_Amount">30.00</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

How can the value in the Coupon_Amount element be grabbed using parent, children selectors?

I have tried:

```
$('.Order_Coupon').children(".Order_Coupon").html()
```

And also:

```
$(this).closest('.Order_Wrapper').children('.Order_Coupon').html()
```

And:

```
$(this).parents('.Order_Subtotal').children('.Coupon_Amount').html()
```

Comment: post the actual html if you want help with traversing the DOM

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: that's not html structure, it's meaningless indented text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the hierarchy as shown in your description and if, for example, you have the Order_Coupon element selected, you can get the coupon amount by the .children method.

```
var amount=$('.Order_Coupon').children().html();
```

Depending on what you have selected, you may have to use multiple calls of .child to find the coupon_amount element.

```
var amount=$('.Order_Left').children().children().children().html();
```

However, if each of these elements have ids or classes, it's much safer to use the .find method and specify a selector. Find also searches further than one child layer.

```
var amount=$('.Order_Left').find('.Coupon_Amount').html();
```

This way you ensure you get the value of the correct element. If there are more than one child element any of the div's you call .children on, without specifying a selector, you are likely to get very incorrect results.

Comment: jcengineer, your suggestion: var amount=$('.Order_Left').find('.Coupon_Amount').html();
-- worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Why is there a -5 in my original question? Is that a bad thing?